# Why don't ncurses widgets work properly when created in a separate function?

Tags: c++, ncurses, curses

I'm trying to create a series of nested menus using pure ncurses in C++. If I create a menu and post it in main(), it works fine. But if I take the same code and put it in a function that returns a MENU*, it doesn't work at all. Am I missing something?

Code that works:

```
int main() 
{
  /*
   * snipped out the curses startup code
   */ 
  vector<char*> options;
  options.push_back("List");
  options.push_back("Add");
  options.push_back("Delete");
  options.push_back("Exit");

  vector<ITEM*> menu_items(options.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++)
    menu_items[i] = new_item(options[i], NULL);

  MENU *options_menu;
  options_menu = new_menu(&menu_items[0]);

  set_menu_win(options_menu, main_window);
  set_menu_sub(options_menu, derwin(main_window, 6, 20, 3, 3));
  set_menu_mark(options_menu, ">");

  refresh();
  post_menu(options_menu); // this works fine
  wrefresh(main_window);
  /* 
   * snipped out the rest of the stuff
   */
}
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
MENU *make_menu()
{
  /*
   * same as code in previous main()
   */

  return options_menu;
}

int main()
{
  /*
   * snip
   */

  MENU *options_menu = make_menu();
  refresh();
  post_menu(options_menu); // this doesn't do anything
  wrefresh(main_window);

  /*
   * snip
   */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer this for future searchers. It turns out that new_menu takes a pointer to an ITEM list and hangs onto it. If the ITEM list is on the stack of a function, it'll get deleted when the function returns, making the ITEM list invalid.

The solution to this problem is to create the ITEM list on the heap, either via `new` in C++, or using `malloc` (remember to `delete` or `free`!). Another option is to wrap the MENU in a class and keep the ITEM list as a member variable.

The simplest solution is to just make the MENU (or ITEM list) global.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined behavior: `new_menu` expects a NULL-terminated array of `ITEM*` as input, you need a  `menu_items.push_back(0);`.

Comment: Actually in this case it works out because the default size of the vector is 5, and I've only filled it with 4 items, so the 5th one is already NULL. It'll crash with 5 or more items but I can fix it with your suggestion. Either way, it still doesn't post the menu. I think it's because those ITEMs are out of scope when the `post_menu()` gets called. `post_menu` returns `E_NOT_CONNECTED`.

Comment: What happens if you (hack) make the `vector<ITEM*>` a global static?

Comment: it works in that case. It turns out new_menu() takes a pointer  to the ITEM list and just holds onto it, so if that list goes out of scope, the menu can't find it any more. I fixed it by wrapping it all up in a class.

Comment: Hrrm, I guess "connected to a specified item pointer array" on [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/new_menu) is supposed to suggest that, I'd say it's non-obvious.